# Rephrasing a sentence using SpaCy

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, spacy

Is there a function or a library in SpaCy or NLTK to rephrase a sentence/query. I tried a brute force approach of generating synonyms using WordNet and loading the combinations for a query. Any suggestions on speeding up the process?

Comment: You do know that simply replacing synonyms won't work right? See https://twitter.com/VeredShwartz/status/898524159982133248